# Protractor test does not proceed after `sendKeys`

Tags: javascript, protractor, sendkeys

Please find below my very first protractor test.

```
describe ("test Frontend for correct display of Input", function(){
it ("to test input field", function(){

    browser.get("http://localhost:9000");
    element(by.model("searchController.searchParams.query.firstName")).clear().
        sendKeys("firstName", protractor.Key.TAB, "familyName",     protractor.Key.RETURN);
})
})
```

It does proceed to the next side, yet does not let me do anything there after that, as a timeout error is thrown by angular, for example when trying to access the second search field `family Name`. The errors can be found below. How do I fix this?

> Failures: test Frontend for correct display of Input to test input field
>
> Message:
>          Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11      seconds.[...]

Comment: If you do a `('firstName').sendKeys('first');` and then a `('lastName').sendKeys('last');` Do you still get this error? It possible that the page you are testing doesn't have proper tab completion

Comment: Yes, I do. Then, after '(firstName).sendKeys('first')`, the script stops and I get the timeout.

Comment: It sounds like you might have an improper CSS Selector. Could you post the HTML snippet that you are trying to fill out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `conf.js` file, add this (in not done already)

```
allScriptsTimeout: timeout_in_millis
```

the `timeout_in_millis` should be a number which you want to wait before the script timeouts.

The error comes when `Protractor` exceeds a default time of 11s after waiting to synchronise with pending tasks due to Angular.

So increase the `timeout_in_millis` to something like 30seconds or something.

Read more about various timeouts and this one in particular [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular).

Comment: I will try that asap, but to me it appears that not time is the issue here, but rather an error in the script. It does the First two steps and then waits for 10 Seconds at the moment.

Comment: Superb, thanks a lot! This appears to work perfectly!

Comment: Please accept this as an answer if this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do the exact steps manually?

Enter text, tab out...

And hoping this is not on IE, did you try any other browsers?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I am using chrome and/or Safari.